# i'm using react-native-admob-native-ads npm package to show native ads, but i can't see close option for ad or any function to close ad

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-ads-api, native-ads

I created customised native ad and i'm able to show skip option
when i click skip i want to show another ad then in the second ad user can close ads
so i can take them to some another screen in app

in this package i couldn't found any option to close ad

```
nativeAdViewRef.current?.loadAd();
```

using this function to load ad, how can i close?

my requirement is if user clicks skip i need to show another ad after few seconds
i need to show close option

taking user to another screen if clicking on skip is rightway?
or it violates any google ad rules?